# Why aren't controllers for players 3 and 4 detected for Battle Arena mode?

Tags: wii-u, lego-dimensions

We are trying to play the 4-player split screen multiplayer mode of LEGO Dimensions Battle Arena on the Wii U.

I have 3 WiiMotion Plus with Nunchucks controllers and the Wii U gamepad.  We are trying to play with 4 players.

- The Wii U gamepad registers player 1 correctly.
- The first wiimote (left square lit) registers player 2 correctly when the + button is pressed.
- The second and third wiimotes (with their second and third player lights lit on each wiimote respectively) are not being detected by the game.  The screen continues to prompt to press a button on the controllers for players 3 and 4.
- During gameplay, it continues to prompt to connect a Wii remote / pro controller for players 3 and 4.

Why might these 2 player controllers not be detected by LEGO Dimensions?  They are registered with the WiiU system and they have fresh batteries, and their led lights indicate the appropriate player positions.

Comment: I also put a ticket in with WB Games support, so if I find out anything, I'll update the question or add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my kid failed to allow all of the most recent updates to download and patch the game.  Once those were done, I started up Battle Arena and was able to get each controller recognized via the + in order of

1. Gamepad
2. Wiimote with Plus Attachment with Nyko nunchuk
3. Wiimote with Plus Attachment with Nintendo nunchuk
4. Wiimote Plus with Nintendo nunchuk

Lego Capture the Flag with Finn vs B.A.vs. The Doctor vs. Peter Venkman is fun.